# Facebooker extended permissions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, ruby-on-rails-plugins, facebooker

Facebook gives access to
users' emails via the extended permission.

There's also a way in JS and PHP to force users to grant the
permission when they accept the app's TOS -
http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Extended_permissions

Is there a way that I can do this with Facebooker?

Regards..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it just like that :

:jquery , :app_settings => " { permsToRequestOnConnect : 'email' }"} %>
 'facebook') + '\'') %>

Note: Also get the last version of facebooker, because previus version dont support extended permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes

this in your application.html.erb

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("jquery", "1.4.2");
</script>

<%= fb_connect_javascript_tag %> 
<%= init_fb_connect "XFBML", {:js => :jquery , :app_settings =>  " { permsToRequestOnConnect : 'publish_stream' }"} %>
```

and this in your viewtamplate

```
<%= fb_login_button 'window.location = "/nextview";', :size => :medium, :length => :long, :v => 2 %>
```