# facebook_session.user.email = nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, authlogic

I'm using authlogic_facebook_connect plugin on my RoR app.  Looking to get extended permission from the user to acquire their facebook email address so that I can use this email to store in the database as their "myapp.com" registration email.  This way a user can come to the site and click on the facebook connect button and be automatically signed up with my site as well.  I know that I need to ask the user for their permission before I can get their facebook email, but I can't find anything around on how to do that..
(fyi I've tried simply getting email from facebook_session.user.email, but of course it's nil due to the permission restrictions)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebooker extended permissions??](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526940/facebooker-extended-permissions)