# Why I can not get the email from facebook connecting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

I hava connected the facebook by facebooker gem, and I can get the uid and name from facebook. But the email and pic are both gone, I guess i hava no permission ? who can help me, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specifically ask for the email address.. Specifically, when the authorization page on facebook.com lists what the application wants, if you want "email" to be returned, you have to requests "email".

[This SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526940/facebooker-extended-permissions) has an example on how to get email in the facebooker permissions.

For the picture, it's very simple -- just use `http://graph.facebook.com/{id}/picture` -- this works with people, events, groups, pages.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions